# How much do I need to know before applying for my first front end development job?

Tags: websites

I am trying to fill in the gaps in my front end knowledge with the aim of producing a portfolio demonstrating my skills. I have a number of years doing personal stuff, but only 2 months as an intern at a startup.

What level of skill will an employer want me to have?

Comment: That depends entirely on your employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What level of skill will an employer want me to have?

There are many employers out there in the vast world. The jobs they need filled differ significantly. It's not possible to definitively say "once you have *this* you will get hired".

An employer will want a level of skills that match the specific job they are trying to fill. Not much more, and not much less. The specifics vary by locale, by industry, by size of company, and by the companies themselves.

Thus, the specifics of such a general question as yours are not really answerable.

Instead of asking such a general question, look at the web sites that post jobs for the part of the world where you intend to work. Look at jobs for entry-level front end developers. Note what kinds of experience, and what levels of experience they require. Let that be your guide.

If the job ads don't specify a specific level of experience (for example "3 years Javascript"), then you can assume that the level of experience required isn't an important factor for that job. Particularly for entry-level position, "exposure" is what the employer is after - they will expect to train on the specific job requirements anyway.

For non-entry-level positions, this might mean that they want "experience in a working role", without worrying about how long that experience was.

Comment: My problem is that the job adverts tend not to state how much experience they want. They often just say, "Experience of Javascript development" with no clue as to whether I need to be just familiar with it or be a master with 10 years experience.

Comment: Do you think that would apply to these examples? http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/64215/front-end-engineer-neverbland, http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/64525/front-end-developer-qmetric There are a lot with very similar copy which I've found ambiguous.